# cython inheritance

Tags: inheritance, cython

I have a A.pxd (with just declaration of functions) and A.pyx that contains just a class A with all the function body.

Than I have B that inherits from A,

and for B I have B.pxd with some functions

B.pyx

```
class Bclass(A):
    #all the funcions body
```

I want to now how to tell to B.pyx to ricognise A as a type name?

what i do is:

B.pyx

```
cimport A
import A
from A import Aclass
cdef Bclass(Aclass):
   #body
```

but it says me: A is not a type name

If i do this in just one file.pyx it works without problems but working with files.pxd it does not go.

Answer (score 12):

Use

```python
from A cimport Aclass
cdef class Bclass(Aclass):
    # ...
```

or

```python
cimport A
cdef class Bclass(A.Aclass):
    # ...
```

Note that `Aclass` must be `cdef`'fed class, Cython [extension types](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#subclassing) *cannot* inherit from Python classes.

Comment: When i do cimport A it means that i'm importing the A.pxd,right?

Comment: And it gives me no more error for the argument Bclass(A.Aclass) but when i do a cast of a Btype into an Atype it says: <castInA> is not a type identifier. And of course the <castinA> is defined like a ctypedef struct in the A.pxd, Should i import something specifically?

Comment: what is `castinA` ? Use `<Aclass>myBclassInstance` instead

Comment: Then please mark the question as answered. I'm glad I could help you. :)